# Ruby on Rails неразбериха в файлах приложения

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

посоветуйте хорошую книгу по рельсам ,  не сильно древнюю.
Я не могу разобраться в какие файлы какой код писать.
Есть модели- создал и прописал туда модель базы 1 файл -1 таблица
там же есть файл апликейшн рекорд
чтоб работать с БД куда писать мать его код ?
В котроллерах есть апликешен контреллер рб
райк и миграйт сделал

Задача написать АПИ
ЧТо такое МВЦ понимаю,и что такое контроллер вьюха и модель и где они лежат

Answer (score 0):

Книга для новичков - Agile Web Development with Rails 6 Майкла Харта (это самая свежая мажорная версия Rails на данный момент). Не уверен, что она уже была переведена на русский, поэтому если нет - можно спуститься на версию пониже (Rails 5) и найти на русском.